# How to test JavaScriptCore (non-V8 WebKit) performance on Windows?

Tags: javascript, windows, webkit, performance-testing, javascriptcore

I've been playing around with "optimizing" JavaScript as of late - it's fun and, not surprisingly, is very implementation dependent. That is, [Chrome's V8, Firefox's *Monkey, and even IE's Chakra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ECMAScript_engines) can all excel in some areas while performing disappointingly in others.

Now I would like to look at JSC (JavaScriptCore) performance for general heuristics on a desktop .. however, I *only* have a Windows 7 PC available. Thus the question is:

*How can JSC (JavaScriptCore [Nitro/SquirrelMonkey?] / non-V8 WebKit) performance be tested on a Windows-based PC?*

---

The goal is to identify performance patterns, not necessarily absolute performance. The tests are merely concerning the implementation of ECMAScript itself, including the magical JIT/caching that occurs, and not DOM interactions or rendering / layout speed.

I know the the predominate (only?) implementation using JSC is Safari (for OS X and i* devices); Safari 5.1.x was released for Windows, but was over 2 years ago - and much has changed since then.